Issues with pip following the installation of Python 3.13 on Ubuntu
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
This computer originally had Python 3.8 installed. However, I needed to use Python 3.13. To achieve this, I added the Deadsnakes PPA and installed Python 3.13. I then removed Python 3.8 and installed pip.
Now, I'm unable to use pip. When I try to, I receive the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 57, in <module>
from pkg_resources.extern import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'pkg_resources.extern' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/init.py)
there is any way to solve this?
I added the Deadsnakes PPA and installed Python 3.13. I then removed Python 3.8 and installed pip.

Possibly, the system is still looking for python3.8. Have you exported python3.13 to the system path in your bashrc?
Also, you can have multiple Python versions at once. A common practice is to work with a Python virtual environment, which you can set up with any of the versions available on your system.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
